# Netty4.1: SimpleChannelPool reconnection with schedule event

Tags: netty

I am trying to build a Netty Client which makes multiple TCP connections to various addresses (or just different ports). And if the channel of any connection is closed, I want it to be able to reconnect after a certain period of delay time. Here is some code trying to achieve this:

```
private ChannelPoolMap<InetSocketAddress, SimpleChannelPool> poolMap
        = new AbstractChannelPoolMap<InetSocketAddress, SimpleChannelPool>() {
    @Override
    protected SimpleChannelPool newPool(InetSocketAddress key) {
        return new SimpleChannelPool(
                clientBootstrap.remoteAddress(key),
                simpleChannelPoolHandler);
    }
};

private void doConnect(InetSocketAddress address) {
    final SimpleChannelPool pool = poolMap.get(address);
    Future<Channel> f = pool.acquire();
    f.addListener(
            (FutureListener<Channel>) (Future<Channel> future) -> {
                if(future.isSuccess()){
                    Channel ch = f.getNow();                        
                    ch.closeFuture().addListener(closeFuture -> {
                        log.info("closed: reconnecting");
                        doConnect(address);
                    });
                    pool.release(ch);
                }else{
                    log.info("failed to connect, retry in 5 second");
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                    doConnect(address);
                }

            });
}

public void remoteConnect() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        InetSocketAddress address = new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 8300 + i);
        doConnect(address);

    }
}
```

`clientBootstrap` and `simpleChannelPoolHandler` are created as Spring bean, therefore I am not going to show here unless it is necessary.

As shown above, I am using `Thread.sleep(5000)` to simulate a delay before I reconnect. It is not working since it will block the other connected channel in the same thread from receiving new data.

I have also tried to use `ch.eventLoop().schedule(..)`, but doing so will throw a NullPointerException if the reconnection fails (since the channel getting from `pool.acquire()` would be null).

How should I get an eventLoop from this situation to make a schedule? Or what other options do I have to process?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your own ScheduledExecutorSevice and schedule the work there.  If you just want to test it out then why don't you try using netty's [GlobalEventExecutor](https://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/util/concurrent/GlobalEventExecutor.html) to schedule the reconnect.

Comment: thanks a lot! Didn't aware of `GlobalEventExecutor`. Using an instance of it to schedule the reconnect and it is working as the way I wanted.